# Spring-Integration: Config of TaskExecutors in the Pollers for Splitter and Routers to increae the concurrent processing

Tags: spring, spring-integration

[image]This is the Spring-Integration-config I have:

```
jdbc-inbound-adapter --> 1st QueueChannel --> Splitter --> Router --> ServiceActivator -->outbound-channel-adapter
```

When I execute a load of 6000messages which are in a table to be picked up by the jdbc-inbound-adapter it takes 34Mins to get all these messages processed.

And I observed it takes lot of time to get a message to move from Splitter to Router. To decrease the time can I use the below configuration: (**Please see the Poller fixed-delay and receive-timeout**)

```
<si:splitter input-channel="firstQueueChannel" output-channel="splitQueueChannel" auto-startup="true" send-timeout="1">
    <si:poller fixed-delay="50" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="5000" max-messages-per-poll="200" task-executor="messageTypeSplitterTaskExecutor"/>
</si:splitter>

<task:executor id="messageTypeSplitterTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-20" queue-capacity="10" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<si:router input-channel="splitQueueChannel" ref="messageTypeRouter" method ="routeMessage" auto-startup="true" >
    <si:poller fixed-delay="50" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="5000" max-messages-per-poll="200" task-executor="messageTypeRouterTaskExecutor"/>     
</si:router>

<task:executor id="messageTypeRouterTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-20" queue-capacity="10" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

My Question here is: Should I use fixed-rate or fixed-delay on the Poller and should the receive-timeout should be 0 as suggested by Gary in this link:
[Spring integration - Queue/Poller seems to exhaust threadpool without any action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811831/spring-integration-queue-poller-seems-to-exhaust-threadpool-without-any-action)

It would be great if some one can point me in the right direction. We get a load of 400K messages on 30% load

Update:
This is the jdbc-inbound-adapter config and the adapter uses the puts the messages on the 'firstQueueChannel':

```
 <si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInboundAdapter"
    channel="firstQueueChannel" data-source="myDataSource"
    auto-startup="true"
    query="SELECT * FROM STAGE_TABLE WHERE STATUS='WAITING'  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
    update="UPDATE STAGE_TABLE SET STATUS='IN_PROGRESS' WHERE ID IN (:Id)"
    max-rows-per-poll="100" row-mapper="rowMapper"
    update-per-row="true">

    <si:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <si:advice-chain> 
            <ref bean="txAdvice"/> 
            <ref bean="inboundAdapterConfiguration"/> 
        </si:advice-chain>
    </si:poller>
</si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

**UPDATE2:**
This is the high-level with all the details:

```
  JdbcInboundAdapter  --> Splitter ---> Router ---> Service-Activators---> Router (Routed by Result Category) ---> Service Activators --> Router (Routed by Result Type) ---> Service Activators ---> Aggregator  --> Outboundchannel adapter
```

Below is the complete configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:si="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:si-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc-2.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!--This channel is linked to the inbound-adapter --> 
<si:channel id="firstQueueChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="200"/>
</si:channel>

<bean id="mapperUtil" class="com.foo.service.process.mapper.common.MapperUtil"></bean>

<bean id="rowMapperForHighPriority" class="com.foo.service.process.mapper.HighPriorityResultStatusMapper"></bean>

<bean id="inboundAdapterPollingConfiguration" class="com.foo.service.download.retriever.impl.InboundAdapterPollingConfigurationImpl">
    <property name="channel" ref="firstQueueChannel"/>
    <property name="jdbcInboundAdapter" ref="jdbcInboundAdapter"/>      
</bean>


 <!--#################1. JDBC-INBOUND-ADAPTER: This pushes messages to the channel ###########################--> 
<si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInboundAdapter"
    channel="firstQueueChannel" data-source="myDataSource"
    auto-startup="true"
    query="SELECT * FROM STAGE_TABLE WHERE STATUS='WAITING'  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
    update="UPDATE STAGE_TABLE SET STATUS='IN_PROGRESS' WHERE ID IN (:Id)"
    max-rows-per-poll="100" row-mapper="rowMapper"
    update-per-row="true">

    <si:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <si:advice-chain> 
            <ref bean="txAdvice"/> 
            <ref bean="inboundAdapterConfiguration"/> 
        </si:advice-chain>
    </si:poller>
</si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="false"/>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!--#################2. This splits the Payload of List to individual payload ################################--> 
<si:splitter input-channel="firstQueueChannel" output-channel="splitQueueChannel" auto-startup="true" send-timeout="1">
    <si:poller fixed-delay="50" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="5000" max-messages-per-poll="200" task-executor="messageTypeSplitterTaskExecutor"/>
</si:splitter>

<si:channel id="splitQueueChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="200"/>
</si:channel>

<task:executor id="messageTypeSplitterTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-20" queue-capacity="10" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!--##################################### 3. Here we get 2 types of messages STATUS, RESULT and RESULT_SET this ROUTER would route messages depending on the message type  #####################################-->  
<si:router input-channel="splitQueueChannel" ref="messageTypeRouter" method ="routeMessage" auto-startup="true" >
    <si:poller fixed-delay="50" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" receive-timeout="5000" max-messages-per-poll="200" task-executor="messageTypeRouterTaskExecutor"/>     
</si:router>

<bean id="messageTypeHighRouter" class="com.foo.service.process.router.MessageTypeHighRouter"/>

<task:executor id="messageTypeRouterTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-20" queue-capacity="10" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


<!-- STATUS MESSAGES GO TO THIS CHANNEL --> 
<si:channel id="statusHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
 </si:channel>

<!--#####################################4.  SERVICE ACTIVATOR TO PROCESS THE STATUS-MESSAGES #####################################-->
<si:service-activator input-channel="statusHighChannel" ref="statusConsumeService" method="consumeStatus" output-channel="ackHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="statusMessageHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>
<task:executor id="statusMessageHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="5" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- ACKNOWLEDGE CHANNEL -->
<si:channel id="ackHighChannel"/>


<!--#####################################5.  Processing Results  #####################################-->
<!-- Have a Router to Route results according to OrderType on OrderTypeHandler Channels 
     and on each channel have a service activator to process the results accordingly   -->

<!-- BELOW ARE THE CHANNEL DEFINITIONS FOR RESULT AND RESULT_SET -->
<si:channel id="highSimpleOrderResultChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:channel id="resultHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:channel id="resultOrderSetHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:channel id="resultOrderSetSplitHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>   

<!--##################################### 6. This service-activator would get a RESULT_SET Object which would convert it to List<RESULT> and returns it #####################################-->
<si:service-activator input-channel="resultOrderSetHighChannel"
    output-channel="resultOrderSetSplitHighChannel" ref="resultOrderSetSplitter"
    method="splitOrderSetResultToOrderResult">
    <si:poller task-executor="resultMessageSetHighTaskExecutor"
        fixed-delay="1000" />
</si:service-activator> 

<task:executor id="resultMessageSetHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!--##################################### 7. This bean converts RESULT Object to List<RESULT> object and the list size is 1 #####################################-->
<bean id="simpleOrderResultMapper" class="com.foo.service.process.transformer.SimpleMissionResultTransformer"/>

<si:transformer id="simpleOrderResultHighTransformer" input-channel="highSimpleOrderResultChannel" method="transform" output-channel="resultOrderSetSplitHighChannel" ref="simpleOrderResultMapper"/>


<bean id="splitterBean" class="com.foo.service.process.impl.MessageSplitter" />

<!--#####################################8. SPLITTER : LIST<RESULT> to RESULT #####################################-->
<si:chain input-channel="resultOrderSetSplitHighChannel" output-channel="resultHighChannel">
    <si:splitter ref="splitterBean"/> 
</si:chain>


<!--##################################### 9. This service would update the OrderTypeCategory attribute in the payload #####################################-->
<si:service-activator input-channel="resultHighChannel"
    output-channel="processResultHighChannel" ref="resultAssignCategoryService"
    method="processCategoryResults">
    <si:poller task-executor="resultMessageHighTaskExecutor"
        fixed-delay="1000" />
</si:service-activator> 
<task:executor id="resultMessageHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!--#####################################10. This router uses the OrderTypeCategory attribute to route to the below channels #####################################-->
<si:router input-channel="processResultHighChannel"  ref="orderTypeCategoryRouter" method ="routeHighMessage"/> 

<!-- ORDER-TYPE-CATEGORY Channels -->
<si:channel id="ORDERHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="NOTIFICATION_SOFTWARE_UPDATEHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="NOTIFICATION_USERHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="ALERTHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="FILE_WATCHERHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="ERRORHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:transformer id="highTransformer" input-channel="ERRORHighChannel" method="transform" output-channel="ackHighChannel" ref="OrderResultsMessageTransformer"/>

<!--11. This service-activator would update the OrderType attribute in the payload-->
<si:service-activator input-channel="ORDERHighChannel" output-channel="processORDERHighChannel" ref="resultAssignCategoryService" method="processOrderResults" >
    <si:poller task-executor="resultOrderHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000" />        
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="resultOrderHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!--#######12. This router would use the OrderType Attribute to route to different channels and the service-activators on the channels will process the messages#####-->
<si:router input-channel="processORDERHighChannel" ref ="orderTypeRouter" method ="routeHighMessage"/>

<!--############13. Below are the list of channels and service-activators which process the messages when they reach their respective channels###############-->

    <!-- Get_Properties Handler   -->
<si:channel id="GET_PROPERTIESHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="GET_PROPERTIESHighChannel" ref="getPropertiesHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="getPropertiesHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="getPropertiesHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


<!-- Set_Properties Handler   -->
<si:channel id="SET_PROPERTIESHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="SET_PROPERTIESHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="setPropertiesHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="setPropertiesHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- ADD_PROPERTIES Handler   --> 
<si:channel id="ADD_AGENT_PROPERTIESHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="ADD_AGENT_PROPERTIESHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="addAgentPropertiesHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="addAgentPropertiesHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- FILE_DOWNLOAD_ Handler   -->    
<si:channel id="FILE_DOWNLOAD_HighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="FILE_DOWNLOAD_HighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="fileDownloadHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="fileDownloadHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- GROOVY_SCRIPT_EXECUTION Handler   -->  
<si:channel id="GROOVY_SCRIPT_EXECUTIONHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="GROOVY_SCRIPT_EXECUTIONHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="groovyScriptExecutionHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="groovyScriptExecutionHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- SHELL_SCRIPT_EXECUTION Handler   -->   
<si:channel id="SHELL_SCRIPT_EXECUTIONHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="SHELL_SCRIPT_EXECUTIONHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="shellScriptExecutionHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="shellScriptExecutionHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- NOTIFY_DEVICE Handler   -->    
<si:channel id="NOTIFY_DEVICEHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="NOTIFY_DEVICEHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="notifyDeviceHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="notifyDeviceHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- AGENT_REGISTRATION Handler   -->   
<si:channel id="AGENT_REGISTRATIONHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="REGISTRATIONHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="registrationHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="registrationHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- FILE_WATCHER Handler   --> 
<si:channel id="FILE_WATCHERHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="FILE_WATCHERHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="fileWatcherHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="fileWatcherHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- CONFIGURE_FAST_POLLING Handler   -->   
<si:channel id="CONFIGURE_POLLINGHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="CONFIGURE_POLLINGHighChannel" ref="updateResultStatusHandler" method="handleRawMissionResult" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="configurePollingHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="configurePollingHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- FILE_UPLOAD_TO_ENTERPRISE Handler, This is Murthy's Service   -->
<si:channel id="FILE_UPLOAD_HighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="FILE_UPLOAD_HighChannel" expression="@fileTransferHandler.handleMissionResult(payload,false,headers)" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="fileUploadToEnterpriseHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="fileUploadHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="10-30" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


<!-- DB_SCRIPT_EXECUTION Handler   -->  
<si:channel id="DB_SCRIPT_EXECUTIONHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="DB_SCRIPT_EXECUTIONHighChannel" expression="@fileTransferHandler.handleMissionResult(payload,false,headers)" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="dbScriptExecutionHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="dbScriptExecutionHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- FILE_SEARCH Handler   -->  
<si:channel id="FILE_SEARCHHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel>

<si:service-activator input-channel="FILE_SEARCHHighChannel" expression="@fileSearchHandler.handleMissionResult(payload,headers)" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="fileSearchHandlerHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="fileSearchHandlerHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/> 

<!--Category Handlers   -->

<!-- DIRECTORY_WATCHER Handler   -->
<si:channel id="FILE_WATCHER_CATEGORYHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="50"/>
</si:channel> 

<si:service-activator input-channel="FILE_WATCHER_CATEGORYHighChannel" expression="@fileTransferHandler.handleMissionResult(payload,true,headers)" output-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="fileWatcherHandlerCategoryHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<task:executor id="fileWatcherHandlerCategoryHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- Below are the channels required to do aggregation -->
<si:channel id="prepareResultsHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="500"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="aggregateHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="500"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="aggregateFileSearchHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="500"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="aggregateCommonHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="500"/>
</si:channel>
<si:channel id="discardHighChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="500"/>
</si:channel>

<!--######################################14.AGGREGATOR for the Result Messages######################################################################-->  
<bean id="resultAggregatorBean" class="com.foo.service.consume.result.ResultAggregator" />

<si:aggregator input-channel="prepareResultsHighChannel" output-channel="aggregateHighChannel"
ref="resultAggregatorBean" method="send" release-strategy="resultAggregatorBean"
release-strategy-method="release" correlation-strategy="resultAggregatorBean"
correlation-strategy-method="correlate" send-partial-result-on-expiry="false" send-timeout="300000" discard-channel="discardHighChannel"/>

<!--#####################################15 ROUTER - To send to different activators depending on the type of result#############################################################################-->
<bean id="aggregatorRouter" class="com.foo.service.process.router.AggregatorRouter"/>   
<si:router input-channel="aggregateHighChannel"  ref="aggregatorRouter" method ="routeHighMessage"/>     

<bean id="aggregatorUtil" class="com.foo.model.process.aggregate.AggregatorUtil"/>

<bean id="aggregateFileSearchResultService" class="com.foo.model.process.aggregate.impl.AggregateFileSearchResultServiceImpl">
    <property name="missionResultDAO" ref="missionResultDAO"/>
    <property name="aggregatorUtil" ref="aggregatorUtil"/>
</bean> 

<!-- SERVICE-ACTIVATOR TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON HIGH PRIORITY, DEFAULT OR ADVANCE FILE-SEARCH-CHANNEL   -->
<si:service-activator input-channel="aggregateFileSearchHighChannel"  ref="aggregateFileSearchResultService" method="processAggregatorResponse" output-channel="ackHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="aggregateResultHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<!-- TASK EXECUTOR TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON ON HIGH PRIORITY FILE-SEARCH-CHANNEL   -->
<task:executor id="aggregateResultHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-15" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!-- BEAN TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON COMMON-CHANNEL   -->
<bean id="aggregateCommonResultService" class="com.foo.model.process.aggregate.impl.AggregateCommonResultServiceImpl">
    <property name="missionResultDAO" ref="missionResultDAO"/>
    <property name="aggregatorUtil" ref="aggregatorUtil"/>
</bean> 

<!-- SERVICE-ACTIVATOR TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON COMMON-CHANNEL   -->
<si:service-activator input-channel="aggregateCommonHighChannel"  ref="aggregateCommonResultService" method="processAggregatorResponse" output-channel="ackHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="aggregateCommonHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>

<!-- TASK EXECUTOR TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON COMMON-CHANNEL   -->
<task:executor id="aggregateCommonHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-30" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>


<bean id="evaluateResultService" class="com.foo.model.process.aggregate.impl.EvaluateResultServiceImpl">
    <property name="missionResultDAO" ref="missionResultDAO"/>
</bean>

<bean id="discardResultDAO" class="com.foo.dao.mission.result.impl.DiscardResultDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
    <property name="missionResultDAO" ref="missionResultDAO"/>
</bean>

<!-- BEAN TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON DISCARD-CHANNEL   -->
<bean id="discardResultService" class="com.foo.model.process.aggregate.impl.DiscardResultServiceImpl">
    <property name="discardResultDAO" ref="discardResultDAO"/>
    <property name="aggregatorUtil" ref="aggregatorUtil"/>
</bean>     

<!-- SERVICE-ACTIVATOR TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON DISCARD-CHANNEL   -->
<si:service-activator input-channel="discardHighChannel"  ref="discardResultService" method="applyFailureStatusToMessagesOnDiscardChannel" output-channel="ackHighChannel">
    <si:poller task-executor="discardHighTaskExecutor" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</si:service-activator>     

<!-- TASK EXECUTOR TO PROCESS MESSAGE ON DISCARD-CHANNEL   -->
<task:executor id="discardHighTaskExecutor" pool-size="2-30" queue-capacity="2" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

<!--###################################16.  dispatch the result###########################################################-->
<!-- THIS IS THE FINAL ELEMENT WHICH WOULD UPDATE THE STAGING TABLE WITH THE MESSAGE STATUS TO SUCESS OR FAILURE -->
<si:outbound-channel-adapter ref="acknowledgementService" method="receiveMessage" channel="ackHighChannel" order="1">       
</si:outbound-channel-adapter>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so many queue channels? You only need one handoff point to multi-thread; try invoking the splitter on the jdbc adapter poller's thread.

EDIT:

What are you trying to achieve by having pretty much every channel a `QueueChannel`? This causes an incredible amount of thread context switching.

I would suggest starting out by having all channels `DirectChannel`s except for `splitQueueChannel` and then add further concurrency downstream if you find you need it. But having pretty much every channel a queue channel is excessive unless there is something specific you are trying to achieve that I am not seeing.

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to invoke the splitter on the jdbc-adapter poller's thread. I have updated my question with the jdbc-adapter config.

Comment: it would be easier if you show all your configuration but just change firstQueueChannel to a simple channel (no queue child element)

Comment: Thanks Gary. Updated my question with the configuration and Integration-graph.

Comment: There was no specific reason to use queue-channels. It was only to not to avoid the OutofMemory errors. If by having the SplitQueueChannel as QueueChannel would take care of the OutOfMemory errors then I can go ahead and use DirectChannel's.

Comment: You should be able to completely control the situation with a `capacity` on that queue - you currently have it set to 200, and the poller threads will block when it's full (as long as you have `CALLER_RUNS` on the TE).

Comment: I have rejection-policy as CALLER_RUNS on all the TE. By using DirectChannel all the services will run in a single thread wouldn't that increase the time of processing the message by all the services.

Comment: I said make just `splitQueueChannel` a queue channel. The poller will hand off to a TE thread which will split the data and dump it into the queue. When the queue is full, those TE threads will block. On the other side of that queue you can have as many threads as you need but you don't need all the downstream channels to be queues.

Comment: Thanks Gary, will use the direct-channels